# Cannot get jquery-ui to work in a Rails partial

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I cannot get a simple input.hover to work in a Rails 3 partial.  Here is my partial _lookupshow.html.erb

```
 I threw the js include tags in the partial to see if that was the problem, it was 
 not the problem

 <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js", "jquery.ui.mouse.min.js" %>
 <table id="sortable" class="lkupdata">
    <tbody class="lkuptbody">
        <% @lookuprows.each do |lkup| %>
            <tr class="lkuprow">
                <td>
                   <input type="text" class="lkupcode" value="<%= lkup.codetype %>"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <input type="text" class="lkupdesc" value="<%= lkup.codedesc %>"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Here is the jquery code in the application.js, I moved this code to lookup.js and it still didn't work.

```
 $('.lkupcode').load(function(){
    $('.lkupcode').hover(function(){
        alert("This is working");
    });
 });
```

I had the above code in the document.ready section but moved it to a .load section.  Any idea why something this simple does not work?  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the load function call is correct, it should be

```
$(function() {
  $('.lkupcode').hover(function() {
    alert("This is working");
  });
});
```

If that doesn't work, it could be that you're including jQuery UI in the document body; perhaps it would work if that's moved into the `<head>`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i can't get that to work.  I have the jquery-ui in the **`<head>`** but put it in the body just to see if that worked.

Comment: it works if i put that code in the partial itself, but that doesn't seem the proper way for it to work, oh well...